# Fetching records from Many to Many relationship does not work as expected in Phalcon

Tags: many-to-many, phalcon

I have created the phalcon models and relationship as per they provided the document but getting the error "Notice: Undefined property: Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Resultset\Simple::$GroupsMembers in /var/www/html/uno/apps/webservice/controllers/UserController.php on line 245" while trying to fetch related records in many to many relationship.

I have 3 tables users, groups and group_members. group_members contain the relationship for groups and users.I want to get the all subscribed groups for a member therefore I have used below statements in UserController:

```
    $user = Users::find('id = '.$user_id);
    $subscribed_groups = $user->groupsMembers;
    foreach($groupMembers as $groupMember){
        echo $groupMember->groups->title;
    }
```

It gives the error mentioned above.

Please visit the link below to see my tables, models and controller.

http://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/5928/fetching-records-from-many-to-many-relationship-does-not-work-as-expected-in-phalcon

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Calin Rada (http://forum.phalconphp.com/user/283/calinrada) for answer.

Correct answer is:

find() method is returning an instance of Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Resultset\Simple but findFirst() will return an instance of your object (User in your case).

Detail answer on:
http://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/5928/fetching-records-from-many-to-many-relationship-does-not-work-as

Answer (score 0):

You use the alias GroupsMembers but then refer to it as $user->groupsMembers which is causing the undefined property notice.

Adjust your code to

```
$subscribed_groups = $user->GroupsMembers;
```

And it should work.